# HERE API calculate route for multiple vehicles

Tags: here-api, here-fleet-telematics

I'm trying to concise the API requests to HERE API when using a calculateRoute service via fleet telematics API. It seems that API takes waypoints as params to calculate a single route within coordinates provided in the waypoints.

Question: Can we request multiple array of waypoints in a single request? so that I can reduce the number of network requests to HERE API.

For example, request will include something like Array where Waypoints: Array